# Python NameError: name 'X' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, nameerror

When I get into really big code problems, I don't mind, but when I get into these basic things, it really puzzles me.

```
from mlr.MLR import MyLinearRegression as mlr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('baseball.csv', delimiter = ',')

feature_cols = ['RS', 'RA', 'OBP', 'SLG', 'BA']
target_col = 'W'

model = mlr()
model.fit_dataframe(X=feature_cols,y = target_col,dataframe=df)

model.ingest_data(X,y)
```

I get the infamous:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 model.ingest_data(X,y)
>
> NameError: name 'X' is not defined

Did I not define X above as X=feature_cols ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling a function, you're assigning variables (that exist in your namespace) to the function's parameter names (which do NOT exist in your namespace).

If you want to think about it this way, you're assigning those variables inside the *function's* namespace, not inside *your* namespace.

So you would need to use `feature_cols` and `target_col` instead of `X` and `y`.